# Question about Topological Subspace definition

Tags: general-topology, definition

Let $(S,\tau)$ be a topological space, and let $H\subseteq S$.

Using [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Topological_Subspace) definition, we can define the topological subspace $(H,τ_H)$ where $τ_H:=\{ U \cap H : U \in τ \}$.

Now, having just begun my independent study of topology, I found this definition to be a little surprising. Why not just define the subspace so that $τ_H:=\{U\in τ : U\subseteq H\}$?

Comment: Does $\tau\cap H$ even make sense here? $\tau$ is a family of subsets of $S$ while $H$ is a family of points in $S$. In most situations, that would make $\tau\cap H=\varnothing$.

Comment: If the topology on $S$ derives from a metric $d$, then taking the metric $d'=d\restriction_{H \times H}$ for $H$ (same metric, but only for points of $H$), then the $d'$-induced topology on $H$ becomes $\tau_H$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass +1 Good job catching that! I have revised my question to better reflect what I originally meant. (Namely, why not define $τ_H$ to be the set of "open" sets which are contained in $H$?)

Answer (score 1):

Recall that a topological space $(X,τ)$ must have the property that $X\inτ$. That is, $X$ itself must be "open."

The problem with defining $τ_H$ to be $\{U\in τ : U\subseteq H\}$ is that $(H,τ_Η)$ could only be a topology if $H$ is "open" in our original set $S$. We want a definition which allows us to take **any** (nonempty) subset of $S$ and form a topology.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question (basically just saying the same as Pascal):

If $Y \not \in \tau$, then $Y \subset Y$ would not be open, which is an axiom for a topology. Therefore we have to define the subspace topology in a way which does not depend on properties of the subset.

The idea for the definition is the following:

If we have a topological space $(X,\tau)$ and a subset $Y \subset X$, then we want the inclusion map $i \colon Y \rightarrow X$ to be continuous. This means for every open set $U \subset X$ we need the preimage under the inclusion map $i^{-1}(U) = U \cap Y$ to be open in $Y$. We now take th smallest topology such that this is satisfied (which is just taking this as definition for open sets) and that is how the subspace topology is defined.

Comment: The inclusion map being continuous has the pleasant consequence that the restriction of a continuous $f: X \to Y$ to the subspace $H$ is still continuous, as $f\restriction_H = f \circ i$, and then taking the *minimal* topology that $i$ is continuous, makes it the more natural.